# accessing variables from an intended block of nested blocks

Tags: c++, c++11

In the program below, how to retrieve value of aa from Block A in Block C?
We can only access the outermost global aa using scope resolution operator.

Known solutoins:
1. Use different pointers in different blocks
2. Use the variable in parent block before using the current block's variable

I am looking for any other alternative solution

I know that this is not good code. Just curious in understanding how to achieve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

// Global
int aa = 10;

int main()
{
    // Main
    int aa = 20;

    {
        // Block A
        int aa = 30;

        {
            // Block B
            int aa = 40;

            {
                // Block C
                int aa = 50;

                cout << "block C " << aa << endl;
                cout << "block A " << ????? << endl;
                cout << "global" << ::aa << endl;
            }

            cout << "block B " << aa << endl;
        }

        cout << "block A " << aa << endl;
    }

    cout << "main " << aa << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I know that this is not good code. Just curious in understanding how to achieve it.

You can't.

Undecorated use of the variable `aa` will use the one that is in the nearest scope.
Decorated use of the variable, `::aa`, will use the one that is in the scope outside the function.
Decorated use of the variable, `<NS>::aa`, will use the one that is in the scope of the namespace `<NS>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use references.

> ```
> // Block A
> int aa = 30;
> auto& ref_aa = aa;
> {
>     // Block B
>     int aa = 40;
>
>     {
>         // Block C
>         int aa = 50;
>
>         cout << "block C " << aa << endl;
>         cout << "block A " << ref_aa << endl;
>         cout << "global" << ::aa << endl;
>     }
>
>     cout << "block B " << aa << endl;
> }
> ```

Of course, that's quite meaningless; if you can modify the code, then just change the variable names, or refactor it such that fewer blocks are needed (using more functions, for example).